# How can I give single caption for these two figures at the bottom?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have tried `\caption{\label{fig:your-figure}Caption goes here.}`. But it's not working. Can anyone please help?

```
\documentclass[10pt, blue]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        (a)\\
        \includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=9cm]{black1}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{0.01em}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        (b)\\
        \includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=9cm]{black1}
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

For have a caption, you need enclose your images with `figure` environment. Use of `tabular` are superfluous:

```
\documentclass[10pt, blue, demo]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
%    \begin{tabular}{c}
        (a)\\
        \includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=9cm]{black1}
%    \end{tabular}

    \smallskip
%    \begin{tabular}{c}
        (b)\\
        \includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=9cm]{black1}
%    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption goes here.}
    \label{fig:your-figure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `subcaption` package

```
\documentclass[10pt, blue]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}\centering
        \caption{This is Caption a}
            \includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=9cm]{black1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}\centering
        \caption{This is Caption b}
            \includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=9cm]{black1}
    \end{subfigure} 
\caption{This is a caption for a and b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `table` environment, so `\caption` doesn't have anything to actually caption.  Either you encapsulate the two `tabular`s in a `table` environment, or (as I would recommend for a presentation) just forget about `\caption`, and write the description as a simple line of text.